# string::std find method always find a character, even when it's not in the string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, visual-c++, string-parsing

I'm doing a project for school where we are parsing through strings passed in from a text file. However, I'm having problems with string.find. When I run this code:

```
string theFile;
while (inFile)
{
    inFile.getline(line, 512);
    theFile = line;
    bool parsing = true;
    while (parsing){
        Choice *newChoice = new Choice;
        if (theFile.find("|")!= -1) {
            newChoice->lines = theFile.substr(theFile.find("%") + 1, theFile.find("|") - 1); 
            theFile.erase(0, theFile.find("|") + 2); 
            tempNPC->choices.push_back(newChoice); 
        }
        else
           parsing = false;
```

The input looks something like this:

```
| d1% stuff | d2% more stuff |
```

My problem: the if statement is never false. Even once theFile is empty, it still runs the code and thus I get an out-of-bounds error. Any idea why find("|") isn't working?

*Edited to add how I get the string from the file

Comment: What type is `theFile`?

Comment: it's just a .txt file

Comment: .txt is not a type.  You need to show the declaration of `theFile` in your code and not just assume that everyone knows what type you've used.

Comment: oh I misunderstood what you were asking. It is a string.

        `string theFile;
 while (inFile)
 {
  inFile.getline(line, 512);
  theFile = line;`

Comment: Your inner loop is also horrible, it should be `while( theFile.find('|') != string::npos )`.  As you have it, it's both unnecessarily verbose, and leaks memory on the last iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), so you can find out what the return values from `std::string::find` actually mean.  Specifically, if you're not sure a value is present you should compare it to `npos` before using it, not "-1".  And the problem with it continuing to run after your input's exhausted is likely best solved in the input code you don't show, rather than trying to parse some `string` that may or may not be actual input.

UPDATE: as speculated in my comment to vsoftco below, your input logic is broken.  Use this:

```
while (getline(inFile, theFile))
    ...
```

Comment: although `std::string::npos` is defined as `size_type(-1)`, and probably comparing with `-1` should be fine (although I don't know how portable it is).

Comment: @vsoftco: it's slop... and the comparison is only made once... I suspect the erase is mutating a valid line, then re-parsing it because EOF isn't detected properly, such that the *other* `find`s (after the `if`) are getting `npos` - and they're not checking for it at all.  Just slop.

Comment: @TonyD So are you suggesting I change `theFile.erase` to something else?

Comment: @itsmountainman: I'm suggesting you check your file reading logic so it exits cleanly at EOF, and this code to parse the line isn't invoked, then also modify the above so it properly handles input that doesn't conform to expectations: i.e. don't assume all the other `find`s (after the `if`) will actually find the characters you're searching for.

Comment: @itsmountainman: now you've shown the relevant code in a comment: `while (inFile) { inFile.getline(line, 512); theFile = line;` is broken because the `while` condition is checked before the `getline` that might set a bad/fail/eof state: after the `getline` if you use `line` without first checking `inFile` again, you're not guaranteed to have the next line from the file, and as I speculated in my comment to vsoftco above, you end up trying to re-process the partially-`erase`d `string` from the previous line, such that some of the `find`s "fail" (but not the one controlling the `if` statement).

Comment: You *should* be writing `while (getline(inFile, theFile)) ...`.